# How to redirect fprintf output to C socket?

Tags: c, sockets, printf

How can I redirect `fprintf` output to a socket?

I am editing source code which has a lot of `fprintf` calls. It logs to a file. But I would like to redirect this log to a socket.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Unix-like systems, open the socket (getting a file descriptor).

#### Map socket to `stderr`

If you've not yet used `stderr`, you can simply use `dup2()` to make the socket into the output channel.  You may be able to do that even if you have sent some data to the original `stderr`.  The suggestion in the comment about using `fflush()` may be relevant, though `stderr` is usually unbuffered rather than fully buffered (so there is not usually anything to flush).

The `freopen()` function can be used to change the output of a stream such as `stderr` (in particular).  Hmmm, could you use `freopen()` to map `stderr` to `/dev/fd/N` where N is the file descriptor of the socket?  Yes, you probably could.

#### Map socket to other stream

Re-reading your question - I don't see `stderr` in it.  So the `fdopen()` function creates a stream from a file descriptor.  So if you can specify the stream for the logging to write to, you're home.  If you can't specify it but can see it, then the `freopen()` trick above should work here too.

Comment: If you want to use `dup2`, but already wrote to stderr, just do `fflush(stderr)` first.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a "C socket" but you are probably referring to one of two things (WinSock or libsocket). Either way, the basic method I'd use would be to use a `#define` and a simple function, similar to this:

```
#define fprintf(a,b,...) fprintfsock(a,b,__VA_ARGS__)

void fprintfsock( SOCKET s, const char* f, ... )
{
    va_list a;
    va_start( a, f );
    int l = vsnprintf( 0, 0, f, a );
    char* buf = (char*) malloc( l + 1 );
    va_start( a, f );
    vsnprintf( buf, l, f, a );
    send( s, buf, l, 0 );
    free( buf );
}
```

That will work in either, except with libsocket you should typedef or use int for SOCKET.
Make sure you `#undef fprintf` after you're done logging to the socket!

Comment: POSIX.1-2001 says otherwise. Technically "C sockets" (meaning POSIX sockets) are just file descriptors though. The other answers address this a lot better.

Comment: @arjunyg there is more to the world than just POSIX, though. Sockets may be file descriptors on *nix but the specific platform was not provided in the question. However, given the accepted answer, it appears they were indeed asking about sockets on a *nix system. Also in retrospect, this answer is kind of gross ;)

Answer (score 2):

I realize this isn't your question, but you might consider using a tool like netcat instead of messing with the code (which doesn't seem like a trivial change).

You can do something like this (updated to use a log fifo):

```
mkfifo /path/to/log

nc <ip> <port> < /path/to/log
```

http://netcat.sourceforge.net/

Comment: updated to use a fifo instead, which applies more directly to what you're doing.

Comment: socat has a lot more possibilities, including UNIX sockets and whatnot.

Comment: did my answer really deserve a minus? I was just offering an alternative.

Comment: It is good trick. But my software, Snort, does not write to stdout !
Also, I want to increase log performance via socket instead of logging to file.