# Use fprintf on a socket in Windows

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, winsock, msvcrt

I'm trying to use fprintf on a socket on Windows.  Many of the online examples are [UNIX examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776103/how-to-redirect-fprintf-output-to-c-socket).  The equivalent code for Windows is what I'm asking about here.

Ultimately, I'd like to do this:

```
fprintf(file_handle_to_socket, "hello world\r\n");
```

I do not want to use WriteFile, snprintf or anything else.  Just fprintf().

Pseudocode that more or less shows the steps would be helpful.

Here is what I have so far:

```
unsigned short port = enter_port;

int result = 0;
WSADATA wsaData;
result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

struct sockaddr_in local;
memset(&local, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

local.sin_port = htons(port);
local.sin_family = AF_INET;
local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    fprintf(stdout,"invalid socket: error code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}

result = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(stdout,"bind() failed: error code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}

result = listen(sock, 5);

struct sockaddr peer;
memset(&peer, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

SOCKET client = 0;
int size = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
client = accept(sock, &peer, &size);

int OSFileHandle = _open_osfhandle(client, _O_APPEND);
FILE * file_handle_to_socket = fdopen(OSFileHandle, "w+");

fprintf(file_handle_to_socket, "Hello World\r\n");

// hoping this helps -- it doesn't
fflush(file_handle_to_socket);

fclose(file_handle_to_socket);
closesocket(client);

// this throws an exception
WSACleanup();
```

When I run this, nothing comes out on the other end (using putty) and I get an exception at WSACleanup();  The exception at WSACleanup is `An invalid handle was specified`.

**UPDATE** I found a strong lead by [reading this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776103/how-to-redirect-fprintf-output-to-c-socket) more closely.
If I replace:

```
fprintf(file_handle_to_socket, "Hello World\r\n");
```

with

```
fprintfsock(client, "Hello World\r\n");
```

It works.

It's still not a complete answer to my question though. I'm looking to use fprintf() directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A socket is not a file handle, so you cannot use `_open_osfhandle()` to wrap it.  That is why `fprintf()` is not working.  `fprintfsock()` is specifically designed to work with a socket directly.  It is merely a wrapper that formats the data into a local buffer and then uses the socket API `send()` function to send it.  If you really want to use `fprintf()` with a socket, you will have to `#undef fprintf` and then `#define fprintf()` to re-map it to `fprintfsock()` (which will only work if you are using a compiler that supports variadic macros).  Otherwise, just use `fprintfsock()` directly.

Comment: How does one declare and fill in his own FILE struct that uses his own callbacks to call send() and recv() internally?  Is there not a function call that does this?  Like fdopen()?

Comment: No, there is no function that will set up a `FILE` struct using custom callbacks. In fact, now that I think about it, this won't work anyway because `fprintf()` is going to internally call file I/O functions that expect the `FILE*` to ultimately map to a real file, which a socket is not. So you will likely not be able to use `fprintf()` with socket I/O at all. Just use `fprintfsock()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a similar concern with a client part [fprintf on socket using mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24374843/3102264), you should try to create the socket in non overlapped mode :

```
int sock = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, NULL, 0, 0);
```